# Making a bowl / smile/half circle with round border and gradient in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm doing some CSS animations, and I'm trying to create the bowl shape/half-circle with a rounded border something like this [image]

so far I have created a half circle and the waves, the only thing I am missing is the rounded border with gradient, so guide me how do I will achieve this as I am new to animation 
here is the code of what I have done so far, also guide me about my mistake so I can learn from my mistakes, I am also sharing the link of the file that I have created [my animation link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xzjkryRbzLKrHSkRmypLvU0Xg3M8sKhE/view?usp=sharing)

```js
// make some waves.
var ocean = document.getElementById("ocean"),
    waveWidth = 11,
    waveCount = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/waveWidth),
    docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var i = 0; i < waveCount; i++){
  var wave = document.createElement("div");
  wave.className += " wave";
  docFrag.appendChild(wave);
  wave.style.left = i * waveWidth + "px";
  wave.style.webkitAnimationDelay = (i/50) + "s";
}

ocean.appendChild(docFrag);
```

```css
half-circle {
   
margin-top: 10%;
margin-left:40%;
   width: 50px;
    height: 65px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 460px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 460px;
 border: 40px solid;
  
    
  border-left: 40px solid #fce058; 
   border-right: 40px solid #cc9e3a; 
  border-bottom: 40px solid #e4bf49; 
  
 
    border-top: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
body{
  height:auto;
  margin:0;
}

#ocean{
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:200%;
  min-height:100%;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
  linear,
  left bottom,
  left top,
  color-stop(0, rgb(40,40,40)),
  color-stop(0.50, rgb(45,45,45))
  );
}

.wave{
  background:#fff;
  display:inline-block;
  height:110%;
  width:80px;
  z-index:0;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-animation-name:             dostuff; 
  -webkit-animation-duration:         4s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


@-webkit-keyframes dostuff{
  0%{
    height:20%;
  }
  50%{ 
    height:10%;
  }
  100%{ 
    height:20%;
  }
}
html,
body,
#bubbles { height: 100% }
body { overflow: hidden }
#bubbles { padding: 0px 0 }
.bubble {
    width: 90px;
    height:90px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;
    position: absolute;
 z-index:99;
}

.x1 {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.2;
  background: #f3f3f3;
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.x2 {
    left: 410px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite, sideWays 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite, sideWays 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 25s linear infinite, sideWays 5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.x3 {
    left: 500px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3;
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.x4 {
    left: 310px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.35;
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.x5 {
    left: 190px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3; 
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 27s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 27s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 27s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

.x6 {
    left: 450px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3; 
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 17s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 17s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 17s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.x7 {
    left: 600px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3; 
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 23s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 23s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 23s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.x8 {
    left: 467px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3; 
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 24s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 24s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 24s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.x9 {
    left: 350px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.2; 
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.x10 {
    left: 1500px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3; 
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 23s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 23s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 23s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.x11 {
    left: 137px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.3; 
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 24s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 24s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 24s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.x12 {
    left: 150px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    opacity: 0.2; 
    -webkit-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: moveclouds 20s linear infinite, sideWays 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}



@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds { 
    0% { 
        top: 1000px;
    }
    100% { 
        top: -900px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes sideWays { 
    0% { 
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    100% { 
        margin-left:50px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes moveclouds {     
    0% { 
        top:900px;
    }

    100% { 
        top: -900px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes sideWays {
    0% {
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left:50px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds {
    0% { 
        top: 900px;
    }
    100% { 
        top: -900px;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes sideWays {
    0% {
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left:50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="half-circle">
  <div id="ocean">
   <div id="bubbles">
        <div class="bubble x1"></div>
        <div class="bubble x2"></div>
        <div class="bubble x3"></div>
        <div class="bubble x4"></div>
        <div class="bubble x5"></div>
        <div class="bubble x6"></div>
        <div class="bubble x7"></div>
        <div class="bubble x8"></div>
        <div class="bubble x9"></div>
   <div class="bubble x10"></div>
        <div class="bubble x11"></div>
        <div class="bubble x12"></div>
 
       </div>
  
  </div>

</div>
```